GridDB_Python - Group By query execution error
I am looking into griddb again for a project. Currently I want to do data aggregation, and for the syntax I refer to this guidance
I have tried several times, but I always get errors when performing aggregation queries, either by regular group by or group by range.
Here's a snippet of my code:
Execution of simple query
TABLE_NAME = "sensor_test_01"

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo(
    name=TABLE_NAME,
    column_info_list=[
        ["timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
        ["sensor_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["temperature", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["humidity", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    type=griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES,
    row_key=True
)

ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)

query = ts.query("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" limit 5")
try:
    rs = query.fetch(False)
    while rs.has_next():
        data = rs.next()
        print(data)
except griddb.GSException as e:
    for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
        print("[", i, "]")
        print(e.get_error_code(i))
        print(e.get_message(i))

The above section was successfully executed without error.
Execution of aggregation query
#query = ts.query("select timestamp, avg(temperature) as temperature from "+TABLE_NAME+" GROUP BY RANGE timestamp EVERY (20,SECOND)")
query = ts.query("select sensor_id, avg(temperature) as temperature from "+TABLE_NAME+" GROUP BY sensor_id")
try:
    rs = query.fetch(False)
    while rs.has_next():
        data = rs.next()
        print(data)
except griddb.GSException as e:
    for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
        print("[", i, "]")
        print(e.get_error_code(i))
        print(e.get_message(i))

This last section, both the first query with 'group by range' (which I commented) and the second query with regular 'group by', causes an error when executed with following error message:
[151001:TQ_SYNTAX_ERROR_EXECUTION] Syntax error during parse

Has anyone had a similar experience and managed to solve this problem?
